# How to use bdist_rpm like bdist_wininst?

Tags: python, tkinter, centos, rpm, distutils

I am building a Tkinter app and distributing it to both centos and win7

while packaging for win7

```
python setup.py bdist_wininst --install-script script_to_create_shortcut.py
```

works excellently fine with a launcher at both start menu and for desktop

but for CentOS

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm --install-script script_to_create_shortcut_for_linux.py
```

Fails miserably

While later I realized rpm requires the sh file to execute so I used a post-install script

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm --post-install=script_to_create_shortcut_for_linux.py
```

Fails as it is also a python code stored in a sh file

Now, I wrote a sh file that runs `python -c "from module import post_install_script"`
but that too fails as the post-installation script cannot find the proper function name

**setup.py**

```
setup=(..
      scripts=[os.path.join('tickets','complaints.py'),
               os.path.join('tickets','shortcut_linux.py'),
               os.path.join('tickets','tickets.svg')],
...)
```

**shortcut creator or post installation python script**

```
        file_created(os.path.join(sys.prefix,'bin','complaints.py'))
        desktop=get_special_folder_path("CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY")
        startmenu=get_special_folder_path("CSIDL_COMMON_STARTMENU")
        create_shortcut(os.path.join(sys.prefix,'bin','complaints.py'),
                        "Complaints Register",
                        os.path.join(desktop,'complaints.desktop'),
                        '','',
                        os.path.join(sys.prefix,'bin','tickets.svg'))
        file_created(os.path.join(desktop,'complaints.desktop'))
        create_shortcut(os.path.join(sys.prefix,'bin','complaints.py'),
                        "Complaints Register",
                        os.path.join(startmenu,'complaints.desktop'),
                        '','',
                        os.path.join(sys.prefix,'bin','tickets.svg'))
```

It fails with error global name file_created was not defined...

Why rpm is not so simple as wininst which does everything very simply

I spent too much time behind this...Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

**Note**: for wininst the shortcutfile had different paths eg:it dint had 'bin'

Comment: Where is `file_created` supposed to come from? What module has that function?

Comment: iam following this,it is a documentation for postinstallation script
https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html?highlight=create_shortcut#create_shortcut

Comment: Also you realize that `CSIDL_*` are Windows-only paths, right? And `file_created` appears to be a Windows-only bdist function too. You can't just run your for-Windows script and expect it to make an rpm. You need to use `bdist_rpm` with appropriate configuration.

Comment: ohh my bad..so isnt there an option to create a shortcut in linux?? with a post installation script, i mean any work around for this??
I have very little knowledge..

Comment: I don't know what `bdist_rpm` provides. You can certainly create shortcuts like that. There are specifications for how the major desktops do it. They involve creating a special file and registering it with the system I believe (but I'm not sure as I don't use them).

Comment: wininst creates a shorcut file without any errors but for linux there there dont seem much option other than shipping a extra .desktop file to the client system which requires two setup.py seperate for windows and linux...excess coding also..
I was thinking any generic code that does work for both with distutil package..thanks to point out that error of mine though

Comment: Yes, Windows is a single target with specific requirements that bdist handles for you. bdist_rpm *could* offer you the same high-level functions to create a simple `.desktop` file for you but it seems it doesn't. And yes, you need separate configuration for Windows and linux that's not surprising but I don't think `setup.py` is the issue there. Just your Windows post-inst script.

Answer (score -1):

Are you building rpm in `Windows/CentOs?` If it is a `centos system`, you need to install `rpm-build package` for building rpm using ->

`python setup.py bdist_rpm`

So first, install rpm-build package using the command ->

`yum install rpm-build`

Then, run the command ->

`python setup.py bdist_rpm`